# Android Widget multiple instance problem?

Tags: android, widget

I am creating an chat widget in which info update using background(Service)thread,
here when i delete instance of widget then I have to stop all these thread.

So here suggest me how can I stop my all thread on delete of last instance of widget.

updated: 
Here I starting Service class as I create instance (onUpdate of AppWidgetProvider) ,
so every time when I create new instance my onUpdate call and service started again...
so let me know How can I update all instance using single service instance.

Answer (score 0):

use only one named thread, then whenever you can create instance and delete that instance.

Comment: thanks, but how can I know ,,,how many no of instance are created or say this is my last instance...pls check my last update